# Why have later books in the Wrinkle in Time series never got much attention or been adapted?

Tags: adaptations, a-wrinkle-in-time, time-quintet

The 1962 novel [*A Wrinkle in Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time) has been [adapted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time#Adaptations) as a film (twice), a play, an opera, and a graphic novel. Its four lesser-known sequels in the [Time Quintet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Quintet) seem never to have been adapted or to have reached the same level of popularity. I didn't even know until recently that *A Wrinkle in Time* was part of a series!

**Why is this?** Usually a trilogy or quintet of books will be spoken about in the same breath, but *A Wrinkle in Time* seems to exist in most people's minds as a stand-alone story, and to always have been adapted as such. What was "wrong" with the later books that they never got much attention and never got adapted?

Comment: I've not read them, but the reason that sequels often don't get adapted is because they depend too heavily on the earlier books.

Comment: Also, not to put too fine a point on it, but *A Wrinkle in Time* is weird, and has often been stated to be ["unfilmable", and the sequels get weirder](https://gizmodo.com/a-look-at-a-wrinkle-in-times-weird-and-probably-unfilma-1823599173). They also [don't really follow each other](https://www.cbr.com/wrinkle-in-time-sequel-clues/), bouncing back and forth in time with characters entering and exiting the narrative.

Comment: The later books kind of drift further away from norms in story telling and get less easily relatable if I recall correctly.

Comment: If you read the rest of the series, it’s possible that you’ll have some understanding, assuming you agree with me that the first is definitely the strongest of them. IMHO the first chapter of “Wrinkle…" is one of the best first chapters ever written.

Comment: I think a lot of it has to the quality (real or perceived) of the novels.  *A Wrinkle in Time* is a remembered by many readers as a tour de force.  The later books are not bad, but people do not seem to get excited about them in the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Fuzzyboot's analysis there's a couple of other things playing against this

1. Book series don't often get all their books made into movies. CS Lewis' *The Chronicles of Narnia* (7 books) has, at best, made it through *The Silver Chair* (Book 4) before having interest wane. In 2006 [Eragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon_(film)) was made. It's part of [The Inheritance Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritance_Cycle) series, and the movie clearly hints at the story continuing, but it was canceled due to poor reception and revenues.
2. While the series still remains in the fantasy realm, it becomes considerably slower as the books progress (*Wrinkle* was published in 1962, while [An Acceptable Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Acceptable_Time), the final book in the series, was published in 1989). Some of this is due to L'Engle writing the [Polly O'Keefe series](https://us.macmillan.com/series/pollyokeefe), which parallels the *Wrinkle* series, but is not nearly as heavy on the fantasy aspects. As such, there are many fans of *Wrinkle* but [not so many of the latter books](https://thebooknanny.com/reviews/wrw-a-wrinkle-in-time-series/)

   > So, in short, buy A Wrinkle in Time and love it. Borrow A Wind in the Door if you are invested in the characters and want to see more between Meg and Charles. Skip A Swiftly Tilting Planted unless you really like history and not a lot of plotline. Be entertained by Many Waters but don’t think of it as a historical text. Also, read the tie-in series called the O’Keefe Family series for more about Meg and Calvin’s family.

Put a different way, *Wrinkle* suggests a *Lord of the Rings*-style world, where there's big, sweeping powers behind the scenes, leading to a big climax. Instead, it becomes more accidental time travel and YA drama.

Comment: It actually seemed like they had no plan on continuing with Eragon.  Some of the changes they made would make it hard to film the second book without considerable alteration.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Per Wikipedia `Originally, Eragon was supposed to be the first in a franchise based on Paolini's Inheritance Cycle book series with Fangmeirer shooting both Eldest and Brisingr back-to-back. However, following the poor reception of Eragon on its release, the planned franchise was cancelled. `

Comment: TBH, I’m not sure Narnia is the best example here. _The Horse and his Boy_, while a good story, is very much a side story to the main story line. _The Magician's Nephew_ is also arguably a side story (it’s a prequel to the rest of the series, but in much the same sense that Brin's _Sundiver_ is a prequel to the rest of his Uplift books), and gets very deep into the allegorical aspects of Aslan and Narnia (which are a serious minefield in modern times). _The Last Battle_ has the same issues with getting deep into the allegory. On the whole, all three look risky as adaptations.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Actually it fits perfectly for that reason. Narnia's stories are increasingly disjointed (Book 6 precedes Book 1 chronologically, and Book 5 takes place within the timeline of Book 1). While there is some progression of *Wrinkle*, the books do not really tell a contiguous long-running story, they just contain the same characters

Comment: The difference with *Lord of the Rings* is that it was originally conceived as one book.  Tolkien was forced to split it into 3 or 6 books because his publishers thought it was just too long.

Comment: Another decent analogy could be Ender's Game. It also has a whole series of books that follow after it, but it has the same problems as Wrinkle. The stories aren't all that similar to each other, they aren't as popular as the original book, many of the characters don't carry through from book to book, and they get increasingly esoteric and weird. I would argue the Ender's Game movie was better then the Wrinkle movie (though it was by no means great), but it didn't do well enough to justify taking the significant risk of producing a movie for a sequel nobody read

Comment: @Kevin *Speaker for the Dead* is a good book, but unfilmable. It was also a completely disconnected story that Card decided to turn into a sequel by making a grown-up Ender the main character. Who’s completely left everything he did behind him. And all the fans Card has left are LDS and Fundamentalist Christians, but the climax of the movie is a scientist realizing that the biology of the aliens’ life cycle cannot be what it appears, because it contradicts the theory of evolution, which obviously is correct.

Answer (score 16):

I do not have any official word from people who have adapted the first book, but as per my comment, *A Wrinkle in Time* is a weird book, often stated to be "unfilmable" and [the sequels get weirder in some ways](https://gizmodo.com/a-look-at-a-wrinkle-in-times-weird-and-probably-unfilma-1823599173). *A Wind in the Door* starts right after the events of the first book with a new set of extradimensional teachers and a new cosmic threat that involves both stars being snuffed out and making Charles sick.

> Instead of flinging themselves across the universe, Meg, Calvin, Progo, and Principal Jenkins (Meg’s nemesis from Wrinkle, who plays an important role in this story) save Charles Wallace from within by shrinking down and doing battle on a level that’s both cellular and metaphysical. There’s a lot of psychic speaking without words (“kything”) and celestial singing—as well as a very charismatic but non-verbal snake named Louise. All told, and even with blessedly less Charles Wallace this time around, this very interior story would be hugely challenging to adapt.

*A Swiftly Tilting Planet* has a massive time jump and involves time travel to try to ensure a South American dictator doesn't incite nuclear warfare by manipulating his ancestors, with the help of a magical unicorn. *Many Waters* brings in Sandy and Dennys and is a coming-of-age story involving Noah's Ark. The stories don't really follow each other and would likely sell to different crowds.

And probably more salient, [the 2018 adaptation lost a lot of money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time_(2018_film)) and it looks like it's not just a matter of [Hollywood Accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_accounting).

> *A Wrinkle in Time* grossed $100.5 million in the U.S. and Canada, and $32.2 million in other territories, for a worldwide total of $132.7 million. A combined $250 million was spent on production and advertisement. Following Disney's Q2 earnings report in May 2018, Yahoo! Finance deduced the film would lose the studio $86–186 million, and in April 2019, Deadline Hollywood calculated the film lost $130.6 million, when factoring together all expenses and revenues.

I don't have any information on what the return or liability on [the 2003 adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time_(2003_film)) was, but it was not well-received by critics:

> As Diane Ortiz from The University Wire described it, the novel's first film adaptation was a "dud", emphasizing its lack of substantial acting and special effects.[6] In her same article, Eberson acknowledged a similar inadequacy in the special effects and explained how they did not meet the hopes of the creators nor the viewers. Nick Mangione, from Geek.com, suggested that many of the problems associated with the film relate to the creator's decision to dumb-down the concepts from the novel.[7] Mangione pointed out that in her novel, L'Engle trusted her audience and knew they would be able to understand the complex thoughts of the characters.[7] He believes that the film version shows no trust in the audience and spends the entire time simplifying everything and neglecting any of the more complex ideas. Mangione further stated, "It's almost impressive how they managed to take every major location and plot beat from the novel and get absolutely none of it right."

[Madeleine L'Engle didn't like it either](https://www.newsweek.com/i-dare-you-127959)

> **NEWSWEEK: So you've seen the movie?**
> Madeleine L'Engle: I've glimpsed it.
>
> **And did it meet expectations?**
> Oh, yes. I expected it to be bad, and it is.

Comment: So... there's a wrinkle in production?

Comment: @Machavity: Unlike the eponymous scene in the book, I don't think they're going back.

Comment: "this very interior story would be hugely challenging to adapt" - I dunno, ["Fantastic Voyage" (1966)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV6JRApyOjA) was an interior story with a pretty good adaptation to film ... "shrinking down and doing battle on a level that was cellular" - sounds pretty much the same, actually.

Comment: @davidbak: "Fantastic Voyage" was a film first, then Asimov was persuaded to write the novelization. One of the effects of novelization is to make the film look extremely faithful to the book.

Comment: @davidbak: I seriously cannot tell if you are joking about the meaning of "interior story".

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri - w.r.t. Asimov writing a novelization of the film - I did not know that! TY!  w.r.t. not being able to tell if I was joking about "interior story" - mission accomplished .... - and I refuse to let your new information about which was cause and which was effect deter me ...

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Asimov reworked some details of _Fantastic Voyage_ and IMHO the result improves upon the movie.  He wasn't true to the movie, he improved on it.  It's been a long time but IIRC in the movie the submarine just disappeared; in the novel Asimov had the protagonist convince the white blood cell to come after him and the submarine came out of the patient's body when the surviving humans did.  In the movie, shrinking lasts for one hour; in the book, shrinking lasts less time the smaller you shrink, and the size they shrank to worked out to one hour.  And so on.